# Rails Truncate and raw not working together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, truncate

I'm using Rails 4 and come across with very strange problem. That raw and truncate not working properly together.

```
     <%= raw(job.description)%>  # working properly

     <%= raw(truncate(job.description,:length => 200))%>  # Not strip html tags

     <%= truncate((raw job.description),:length => 200)%>  # Not strip html tags
```

What the problem is?

Any help please??

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish so simply try

```
raw job.description.truncate(200)
```

and\or

```
(raw job.description).truncate(200)
```

Comment: Doesn't help me, maybe because I'm using haml...(raw idea.description.truncate(100)) made it

Comment: @yozzz - Only your comment `(raw idea.description.truncate(100))` worked for me too. Perhaps you should make it into an answer and mark as correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `truncate` with `sanitize`

```
truncate(sanitize(job.description, tags: []), length: 200)
```